# How to convert Akka ByteString into String?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but I can honestly not figure it out without setting up some kind of ASCII code -> character mapper myself, which I don't think is the right way to do it.

So currently I'm making a "chat application" with Scala and Akka where I use a separate client and server entity. The client connects to server, sends a message, and the server does something with it.

I got the sending a message working but now I'm stuck on reading the message server-side. Whenever I receive a message I get a ByteString containing the ASCII values of the characters from the message. How do I convert this ByteString into an actual String?

Relevant code (server-side):

```
package chatapp.server

import java.net.InetSocketAddress

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem}
import akka.io.Tcp._
import akka.io.{IO, Tcp}

/**
  * Created by Niels Bokmans on 30-3-2016.
  */
class ServerActor(actorSystem: ActorSystem) extends Actor {
  val Port = 18573
  val Server = "localhost"

  IO(Tcp)(actorSystem) ! Bind(self, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", Port))

  def receive: Receive = {

    case CommandFailed(_: Bind) =>
      println("Failed to start listening on " + Server + ":" + Port)
      context stop self
      actorSystem.terminate()

    case Bound(localAddress: InetSocketAddress) =>
      println("Started listening on " + localAddress)

    case Connected(remote, local) =>
      println("New connection!")
      sender ! Register(self)
    case Received(data) =>
      println(data)
  }
}
```

Picture of server (as you can see it accepts connections -> receives a new connection -> receives a message from the connection):
[image: Server side]

Picture of client (connects to server and then sends message "testmessage")
[image: Client side]

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use

```
scala> val data = ByteString("xyz")
data: akka.util.ByteString = ByteString(120, 121, 122)

scala> data.utf8String
res3: String = xyz
```

see [ByteString API](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/util/ByteString.html),

or on github:

[final def utf8String: String = decodeString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala-2.13/akka/util/ByteString.scala#L940)

Comment: This should come with some caveats. It assumes that the `ByteString` contains complete characters. If it contains only some bytes of a multibyte character then the behaviour is unspecified (as per the docs for `String`).

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `decodeString` method like this:

```
scala> val x = ByteString("abcd")
x: akka.util.ByteString = ByteString(97, 98, 99, 100)

scala> x.decodeString("US-ASCII")
res0: String = abcd
```

Comment: Note that this does not throw on invalid byte sequences for the specified encoding. For example, `ByteString(192).decodeString(ByteString.UTF_8)`